# problem with date() function

Tags: php, mysql

i save in mysql database the time using NOW() function. how can i change the value returned of NOW() function? i want to add 6 hours.

### example

if now() returns **2010-04-03 20:16:27**, i want to save **2010-04-04 02:16:27**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) should do the job:

```
INSERT INTO ...... DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```